# Texture is glitching

Tags: texturing

the texture on my model is glitched and I'm not sure how to fix it. Is there a solution to this? I [image]sincerely thank anyone who offers help!

Comment: hello, maybe a bad unwrap, or bad normal map, or bad setting, maybe pack the image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your advice! I was trying to pack it, but it did not show me the Pack All Into.blend option. If you could provide me further assistance with this I would truly and sincerely appreciate it. 

Comment: You need to go into File > External Data >Pack Resources, if the file is too heavy use another platform like workupload...